# Multiple nested loops in ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I am trying to loop over a list, which is stored in a dict, which is part of another list. my playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: all 
  vars:
    copy_certs:
      - { domain: 'domainname', copy_to: ['/tmp/foo', '/tmp/bar'], restart: [["mailhost", "postfix"], ["mailhost", "dovecot"]] }
      - { domain: 'domainname2', copy_to: ['/tmp/foo2', '/tmp/bar2'], restart: [["mail.lxc", "postfix"]] }
  tasks:
[...]
    - name: Copy Private Key 
      register: copied_key
      copy: src=/etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ item.0.domain }}/privkey.pem dest="{{ item.1 }}/"
      with_subelements:
        - copy_certs
        - copy_to
    - name: Debug (here should be delegates to "item.restart.NUM.0" to restart "item.restart.NUM.1" with_subelements: ...)
      debug: var=item
      with_items: copied_key.results
```

Now i am stack at iterating over the lists, as ansible seems not to support real nesting, but just a few predefined structures for two nested loops.

i would need something like (does not work):

```
with_subelements:
  - copied_key.results
  - item.domain.restart
```

or (wrong syntax for subelements):

```
with_subelements:
  - copied_key.results
  - item.domain
  - restart
```

I already tried to use an redundant list:

```
vars:
  restart_services:
    domainname: [["mailhost", "postfix"]]
tasks:
  - name: Debug
  debug: var=restart_services[item.item.0.domain]
  with_items: copied_key.results
```

as you see it already starts being ugly with `item.item`.

It would need something like

```
  register: [to_restart for to_restart in item['restart']] as services_to_rstart
- debug: var=item # item.0 = hostname item.1 = servicename
  with_items: services_to_restart
```

or if it does not need to be lists to be able to iterate over it even `item.hostname` instead of tuples (actually lists).

It would be really good to have some way to specify loops with nesting instead of using premade filters like `with_subelements`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using "with_nested"? You can check out the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops).

This might work:

```
- name: Copy Private Key
  register: copied_key
  copy: src=/etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ item[0].domain }}/privkey.pem dest="{{ item[1] }}/"
  with_nested:
    - copy_certs
    - copy_certs.copy_to
```

Comment: I tried ``with_nested`` and got similiar weird results with complicated item.item.item chains (maybe indices in between) before opening the issue. The problem is working with a list of nested lists and i realized that ansible does not really support nested lists but just has a few implementations for the most common nesting (two layers, using hashes, ...) but no support for arbitrary nesting. I have not tested your answer yet, as i currently solved the problem differently (using an external script to copy stuff after running ansible).

Comment: The three layers there are not at the copy, but at the restart part, which needs to nest: ´´for domain in domains: for host in domain.hosts: for service in host.services: restart service``. The example in my question is already a bit flattened to avoid the problems, but it's still nasty to do this with pure ansible. Other possiblities than external scripts would probably be using two playbooks or writing custom filters for ansible, which allow more nesting and/or just solve the current usecase.