# Ansible looping over nested variables

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I have a set of variables which define FQDNs.

```
domains:
  - erp: erp.mycompany.com
  - crm: crm.mycompany.com
  - git: git.mycompany.com
```

Indeed, I both need to loop over them and access them namely (in a template file). So accessing them like `domains.erp`works like a charm. But I can't get ansible to loop over these.

Obviously, if I do:

```
- name: Print domains
  debug:
    msg: test {{ item }}
  with_items:
    - "{{ domains }}"
```

It prints both the key and the value… And if I do:

```
- name: Print domains
  debug:
    msg: test {{ domains[{{ item }}] }}
  with_items:
    - "{{ domain }}"
```

But that doesn't work. I also tried the [hashes form](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-hashes) as mentionned in the docs, but didn't get any luck either…

Comment: Ansible seems quite complicated with nested lists, see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206551/multiple-nested-loops-in-ansible. Probably playbooks should not be overengineered or you should implement some custom plugins, as the syntax gets really nasty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I had to use a dict.

It didn't work the first time because unlike `with_items`, which has the items going each on their own line, `with_dict` is a one liner without `-` before the element to loop through.

```
domains:
  erp:
    address: erp.mycompany.com
  crm:
    address: crm.mycompany.com
  git:
    address: git.mycompany.com

# used by letsencrypt
webserverType: apache2
withCerts: true

tasks:

- name: Print phone records
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.value.address }}"
  with_dict: "{{ domains }}"

# I can still access a given domain by its name when needed like so:
{{ domains.erp.address }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you figured out your issue. Your original attempt uses a list of dictionaries that do not contain the same keys, making it difficult to access the values uniformly across each list item.

Your second solution creates a dictionary where the keys refer to other dictionaries.

Another solution than what you posted if you still wanted to use a list:

```
    - hosts: localhost
      vars:
        domains:
          - name: erp
            address: erp.mycompany.com
          - name: crm
            address: crm.mycompany.com
          - name: git
            address: git.mycompany.com
      tasks:
        - name: Print phone records
          debug:
            msg: "{{ item.address }}"
          with_items: "{{ domains }}"
```

To me this approach is simpler but your second approach works as well.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Nevertheless, with this approach, I don't seem to be able to reference my domains by name. If in some other part of my playbook, I need for exemple to access erp's domain name, how can I address it? `domains.0.address` is really error prone.

Comment: Ah you are correct. I misunderstood your use case. Your approach is probably the most reliable way if you need to get the domain items individually and not just loop through them.